# How to add boundary to matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]My following graph has a max value of 14, but looking at graph it appears some portion has been truncated/clipped at the top.

How to add more space at the top although max value for Y axis is 14?

Comment: You just need to extend your ylimit as `plt.ylim(0, 14.5)` or something like ``plt.ylim(0, 15)``

Answer (score 1):

Can you add some source code?

When I am doing just this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([450, 448, 477, 500, 504, 519, 526, 565, 562, 565, 602, 608, 638, 643, 676, 686])
plt.plot(arr, color = 'blue')
plt.grid(1)
```

I do not have such issues.

When i am getting you right your problem is the 14 in the axis. You can adjust this in the [settings of the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIgZ3.png)

The same can be achieved by altering subplots_adjust()

```
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9, bottom = 0.1, left = 0.1, right = 0.9)
```

Normally this should not ne necessary, but since I do not know your code, I can't tell where you have wrecked the setting.

Answer (score 0):

The graph is produced with matplotlib 1.5 or lower. Apart from updating matplotlib, you can set the margin in y direction to something larger than 0,

```
plt.margins(y=0.1)
```

or directly set the limits you want

```
plt.ylim(0,15)
```